# Strange behaviour of array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have this structs:

```
typedef struct {
    // ... other names
    size_t size; // size of frame
} frame_index_t;

typedef struct {
    // ... other names
    size_t         frames_read; // number of read frames
    size_t         frames_size; // size of frames array
    frame_index_t *frames;      // array of indexed frames
} state_t;
```

This is append into array:

```
// ... state allocated earlier
state->frames_size = 0;
state->frames_read = 0;
while (...) {
    if (state->frames_read == state->frames_size) {
        state->frames_size += FRAMES_CHUNK_SIZE; // += 100
        state->frames = realloc(
            state->frames,
            state->frames_size * sizeof(frame_index_t)
        );
        if (!state->frames) {
            goto error;
        }
    }
    state->frames[state->frames_read].size = calculated_frame_size;
    state->frames_read++;
}
state->frames_size = state->frames_read;
state->frames_read = 0;
```

And later I read frames array:

```
while (...) {
    printf(
        "Frame %lu of %lu\n",
        state->frames_read,
        state->frames_size
    );
    if (state->frames[state->frames_read].size == 0) {
        printf("Frame %lu is zero size\n", state->frames_read);
    } else if (state->frames[state->frames_read].size > 2000) {
        printf(
            "Frame %lu is %lu bytes",
            state->frames[state->frames_read].size
        );
    }
    state->frames_read += 1;
}
```

I'm have this output:

```
Frame 2684 of 11737
Frame 2685 of 11737
Frame 3344 is 0 bytes
Frame 2686 of 11737
Frame 2687 of 11737
Frame 2688 of 11737
Frame 2689 of 11737
Frame 2690 of 11737
Frame 2691 of 11737
Frame 2692 of 11737
Frame 4033 is 0 bytes
Frame 2693 of 11737
Frame 2694 of 11737
```

Wow! Whats wrong? I misunderstand it.
Can affect other resources allocated? Can they intersect? Valgring does not say anything about it. No memory leaks, no read errors.

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks! I'm horribly not attentive now, apparently I have to go to sleep

Comment: @user3121023 not important this, only for test, dirty

Comment: In `state->frames[state->frames_read].size = calculated_frame_size;` is `state->frames_read` 0-based or 1-based. If 1-based, the indexing is awry.

Comment: @WeatherVane 0-based